# iOS 10.3 In-App Ratings (or Reviews) with PhoneGap Build - How?

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build, in-app, ios10.3

How to use the new feature in-app ratings/reviews for iOS 10.3 in Phonegap Build?

I tried several plugins, but get a build error for each of them, saying:

> Error - The following 3rd-party plugin is causing the build to fail
>   and may need to be updated to a newer version:
>   cordova-plugin-ios-in-app-ratings-and-reviews

Does someone know a working plugin for in-app reviews?

Answer (score 1):

When troubleshooting 3rd party plugins, I typically:

1. From PhoneGap Build, click the "Log" button then review the output that pops up in a new window. There's a lot of output text usually, so search (CTRL + F) for "error" until you find something that seems relevant.  Usually, you'll see the specific Objective C/Swift error that has occurred
2. Look up the plugin page (cordova-plugin-ios-in-app-ratings-and-reviews) on [npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/).
3. Share the error message with the plugin author on GitHub Issues.